# Centering Google Doc Export CSS

Tags: html, css, google-docs

here's a common thing we do all the time: export from Google docs as 'html' but the end result is a mass of CSS definitions that have a fixed width and is not centered.

I've tried several common HTML fixes and nothing seems to work such as

```
P.blocktext {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 8em
}
...
<P class="blocktext">
```

even the good old fashioned table does nothing

```
<table><tr><td align='center'>
and
<table align='center'><tr><td>
```

For some reason, everything still seems to have the same left-justified text when exported from google doc.

What I'm looking for is CSS code that will perhaps make it more !important than the rest of the CSS so that my document can at least be in the middle of the page.

The actual body content of the Google Doc starts like this:

```
<body class="c29" >
<p class="c14"><span class="c8">
```

I do not want to go into the class definitions because there are hundreds of them.  What we want is a snippet of code that simply aligns the whole thing in the horizontal middle of the screen.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Place this BEFORE the  (or whatever number it happens to be) and your Google Doc export will be perfectly centered. Thanks to Junaid on my dev team for figuring this out!

```
<style>
body{
margin:0 auto;
}
</style>
```